# Mapping Virtual Property Automapper

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, automapper-5

I have some
problem
with mapping models . So I have a entity model

```
public class User
{
    public string UserId { get; set;}

    public ICollection<Group> Groups {get; set;}
}
```

and DTO model

```
public class UserInfo
{   
    public string UserId { get; set;}  

    public List<GroupInfo> Groups {get; set;}
}
```

So I have problem when mapping User  to UserInfo 
Missing configuration type for GroupInfo . 
How intialize second mapping ?

User is mapped to UserInfo as the following:

```
var config = new MapperConfiguratiins(cfg=>cfg.CreateMap<User,UserInfo>()); 
var mapper = config.CreateMapper();
var userInfo = mapper.Map<UserInfo>(user);
```

Comment: Can you please show us how are you mapping User to UserInfo?

Comment: var config = new MapperConfiguratiins(cfg=>cfg.CreateMap<User,UserInfo>()); var mapper = config.CreateMapper(); var userInfo = mapper.Map<UserInfo>(user);

Comment: sorry for mistakes

Comment: Can you also show us the definition for Group and GroupInfo?

Comment: its no such sensitive data something like GroupName and GroupDescription

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this for your `MapperConfiguration`:

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<Group, GroupInfo>();
    cfg.CreateMap<User, UserInfo>();
});
```

Comment: It works , but I forgot that in my Group there is User reference also it is many to many relation. So I ignore this member mapping. otherwise it causing StackOverflow exception. And it is normal. So it is exist some pretty method to workaround or opt.Ignore is best solution?

Comment: Yes, ignoring the user reference in the Group should be the solution to it.